# QT Creator 4 and clang

Tags: c++, windows, qt, clang

When I upgraded qtcreator to version 4, it seems to have added clang to give warnings for dodgy constructs. However, either me or clang are very confused about some of the stuff going on. For instance, this

```
#include <QDialog>

class __declspec(dllexport) QuestionBoxMemory : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:

  virtual ~QuestionBoxMemory();

};
```

gives me a warning weak-vtable suggesting I have no out of line virtual member functions. Which I clearly do. Changing the `dllexport` to `dllimport` removes the warning.

Is this a clang issue? Or is there something else I'm misunderstanding as I'm not sure of the effects of the dllexport/dllimport things

Comment: You might want to check if building with clang on the command line and -Wweak-vtables gives you the same warning (I'd guess so)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - if only I knew how to